# Retrieving the highest varchar value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

We are using the Oracle database.
I have a table with the below records

```
OrderNumber
-----------
JK-PO-01
JK-PO-02
JK-PO-03
```

Using PL/SQL, I would like to get the latest order number (JK-PO-03)

I tried getting the count of the order group and prefixing count var to JK-PO-  but the count_var  is always 0.

```
select count(*) into count_var  from Order where OrderNumber LIKE 'JK-PO-%';
```

Can someone suggest me approach to get the latest OrderNumber ( JK-PO-03) from the table?

Comment: Do you want to count entries or do you want to select them or one of them? Your goal is unclear to me, but the "latest" order number could likely be found using select max(ordernumber) where...

Comment: Thank you Janos. The max(ordernumber)   worked. I misunderstood that  the max() function works with a numeric field

Comment: Be careful with `max` with text fields that contain numbers. If all your numbers always have leading zeros, you're pretty safe. But if you ever get to `JK-PO-100`, then you're in trouble, because that's smaller than `JK-PO-20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "the highest" is actually "max", then

```
SQL> with test (ordernumber) as
  2    (select 'JK-PO-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'JK-PO-02' from dual union all
  4     select 'JK-PO-03' from dual
  5    )
  6  select max(ordernumber)
  7  from test;

MAX(ORDE
--------
JK-PO-03

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, you can sort rows (in descending order) first, and then fetch the one that ranks as the highest:

```
SQL> with test (ordernumber) as
  2    (select 'JK-PO-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'JK-PO-02' from dual union all
  4     select 'JK-PO-03' from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select ordernumber,
  8            row_number() over (order by ordernumber desc) rn
  9     from test
 10    )
 11  select ordernumber
 12  from temp
 13  where rn = 1;

ORDERNUM
--------
JK-PO-03

SQL>
```

---

Example for the `ERS-...` set of data:

```
SQL> with test (ordernumber) as
  2    (select 'ERS-2022-09-02-2003' from dual union all
  3     select 'ERS-2022-09-02-7'    from dual
  4    ),
  5  temp as
  6    (select ordernumber,
  7        regexp_substr(ordernumber, '\d+', 1, 1) num_1,  -- returns 2002
  8        regexp_substr(ordernumber, '\d+', 1, 2) num_2,  -- returns 09
  9        regexp_substr(ordernumber, '\d+', 1, 3) num_3,  -- returns 02
 10        regexp_substr(ordernumber, '\d+', 1, 4) num_4   -- returns 2003 (and 7)
 11      from test
 12    ),
 13  temp2 as
 14    (select ordernumber,
 15       row_number() over (order by to_number(num_1) desc,
 16                                   to_number(num_2) desc,
 17                                   to_number(num_3) desc,
 18                                   to_number(num_4) desc) rn
 19     from temp
 20    )
 21  select ordernumber
 22  from temp2
 23  where rn = 1;

ORDERNUMBER
-------------------
ERS-2022-09-02-2003

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi,
Looks like the  max function  does not work with certain values 
I have the following new values in the table
OrderNumber
ERS-2022-09-02-2003
ERS-2022-09-02-7
ERS-2022-09-02-2002
ERS-2022-09-02-7

The max function returns the incorrect value ERS-2022-09-02-7  instead of ERS-2022-09-02-2003

        select max(OrderNumber) from Order where  OrderNumber like 'ERS-2022-09-02-%';
The query looks ok. Not sure if I am missing something. Please advice

Comment: That's because we are working with strings. There, 7 is "larger" than 2003 (because 7 comes after 2; 003 is irrelevant in this context). Code I posted works on data set you provided while posting the question. If you have different data, then solution depends on what you really have; are there any other variations? Because, it looks like you'll have to extract numbers (as strings), convert them to NUMBER datatype, and then sort these values.

Comment: See edited answer; that piece of code shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are formatted like in your question you could sort and only show the last

```
select OrderNumber
from table
order ny OrderNumber desc
limit 1;
```